# Google forms: send confirmation email with a total price calculated from the answers of the form

Tags: google-forms

I set up the sendMail script succesfully, but when i edit the template of the confirmation email, I can only use ${"Column Name"} with the columns that have form data in them, and not the ones i made after processing the data.

E.g. Form asks for QUANTITY and SINGLE PRICE.

In the spreadsheet, i put those 2 in the first 2 columns and then, in the 3rd column, i multiply them in a "TOTAL" column.

When i write the column name ${"TOTAL"} in my email template, it will turn up blank in the mail i got (while quantity and single price are displayed correctly in the confirmation mail).

The script is the following:

```
function sendEmails() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 4);

var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

// Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

// For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and 
send
// it to the appropriate person.
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
// Get a row object
var rowData = objects[i];

// Generate a personalized email.
// Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) 
with
// the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
var emailSubject = "Quota di partecipazione";

MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.indirizzoEmail, emailSubject, emailText);
} 
}
```

How can i send the total price via mail to the user?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to share this function `fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData)` to understand what is wrong with your code